# How to enable scroll for streamlit_chat keeping input box at same position

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, streamlit, openai-api

I am building a `chatbot` by using `chatgpt3.5` and `streamlit` app.
I am able to put `Input text` at bottom of screen. But as text queries grows my `input text area` also goes down.

Frontend code for `streamlit_chat` https://github.com/AI-Yash/st-chat/blob/main/streamlit_chat/frontend/src/stChat.tsx

Here is the code:

```
import openai
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_chat import message


openai.api_key='API_KEY'


def generate_response(prompt):
    completion=openai.Completion.create(
        engine='text-davinci-003',
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.6,
    )
    message=completion.choices[0].text
    return message

st.title("ChatGPT3.5 BOT")

if 'generated' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['generated'] = []
if 'past' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['past'] = []

def inputchange():


    inp={
        "inputs": {
            "past_user_inputs": st.session_state.past,
            "generated_responses": st.session_state.generated,
            "text": st.session_state.input,
        },
    }
    output=generate_response(inp['inputs']['text'])

    # append user_input and output to state
    st.session_state['past'].append(st.session_state.input)
    st.session_state['generated'].append(output)


# If responses have been generated by the model
if st.session_state['generated']:
    # Reverse iteration through the list
    for i in range(len(st.session_state['generated']) - 1, -1, -1):
        # message from streamlit_chat
        # message(st.session_state['past'][::-1][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + '_user', )
        message(st.session_state['past'][::-1][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + '_user', )
        message(st.session_state['generated'][::-1][i], key=str(i),avatar_style="adventurer",seed=123,)

user_input = st.text_input("Input Message: ", "", key="input", on_change=inputchange)
```

**How to add scroll for `message` just like ChatGPT3.5 does the messages can be scrolled up instead of scrolling the page.**

Comment: Have you got a solution for this scrolling issue. Even for me, I need to scroll manually

Answer (score 1):

This is something that worked for me , will try and update and once I am sure this works.
Do this:

1. pip install the streamlit chat component
2. now install the source code from the git repo
3. in this tax app make he css changes for scroll=true for your container
4. build this for prod and generate the build folder
5. go to source installation and replace your build folder with the one there
6. import and run the package

I think this should work for your case
https://github.com/AI-Yash/st-chat/blob/main/streamlit_chat/frontend/src/stChat.tsx

This is the code file that you would be changing.

Hope this helps; it worked while changing the url.